# Black screen when trying to run DirectX application

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-9

I have been trying to run a sample Directx-11 code from this website:[tutorial 2](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut02.html). (source code download at the end).

***All I get when I try to run the program is a black screen.***

**System Configuration:**

1. Windows 7 64 bit (SP1)
2. Intel Core i5 M520 @ 2.4Ghz
3. RAM: 4GB
4. Intel HD Graphics on core i5 (latest driver )
5. Lenovo Think pad X201

**IDE:**

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
2. Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express with Service Pack.
3. I also installed DirectX 9 SDK from here: [DirectX 9 SDK June 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812)

**Diagnostics:**

1. I ran dxdiag and everything seems to be OK. (DirectDraw and Direct3D are enabled).
2. I tried changing the refresh rate from 50Hz to 60Hz. (*Control Panel->Appearance & Personalization->Display->Screen Resolution->Advanced Setting*)
3. Could not change the hardware acceleration. "Change Settings" option was diabled under "Troubleshooting" tab in the above menu.
4. *System Settings-->Performance Options-->*"Let Windows Choose What's Best For My Computer"

How can I get this tutorial to run? My goal is to run any program in DirectX-11 on my laptop. I am using this to learn DirectX-11. Please let me know if I missed out some detail.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial only create a framework based on DirectX 11, there is no graphics output, so a black window is the expected result.

Comment: thanks a lot... you are right about this tutorial. I tried the other tutorials which do something, and now I have moved on to another error, "Could not initialize Direct3D". Thanks. You have answered my black screen question. Thank you!

Comment: @user2897483 you can post a new topic if you met other errors.